# Electron: How to delete ~/.config/electron-app folder on uninstall time?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have developed a small electron app and stored some cache files inside my `~/.config/electron-app`.
Now I need to remove the ~/.config/electron-app if the app is getting uninstalled. Is there any electron app uninstall event is available?

Many thanks...!

Comment: What is your build target/ target platform? The answer may be different for different targets.

Comment: Obviously, My platform is Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: There is more than one target viable for Ubuntu. [electron-builder targets](https://www.electron.build/configuration/linux)

Comment: @GokulakannanT  Did you get any solution? My target is rpm and deb.

Comment: @MANISHMOHAN Short answer is no. My primary target was windows(nsis). For that, we have an option called `deleteAppDataOnUninstall`. If we set it as true, the cached AppData files were removed when the app is getting uninstalled.  But I can't do it the same for deb. I guess, there are no such options for any Linux based targets.

Comment: @GokulakannanT I found a way to do this. electron builder gives an option for a script to be run after uninstall. I have written there to remove the app folder itself. btw the option is known as "--after-remove"

Comment: Thank you @MANISHMOHAN. It will definitely helpful for someone.